# Spring Tools Suite stopped to exclude test classpath from RUN AS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am using STS to develop a Spring Boot based application. I have multiple maven projects and a patent one to include them all.

I used to run/debug the application by calling RUN AS/DEBUG AS Spring Boot Application to the project that contains the Spring Boot main entry class.

Something changed and the STS loads to the application running classpath the test classes as well. That causes conflicts to spring bean initialization.

Is there any configuration in the workspace that causes that behaviour?

I also created a new workspace, but No luck :-(

Comment: You need to describe your problem using better grammar. Please visit the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Munib Thanks for your comment. I updated the description and tried to be more descriptive. I hope that now it is clear enough the problem

Comment: I would suggest to create a sample application that you can share that reproduces the behavior and attach that to a new issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a 6 month old question, but for those still having the issue:

- You should open your "Run Configurations"
- under "Classpath" tab
- verify that "exclude test classes" is checked

It seems that new STS' Spring Boot App "run configurations" are created without this option (while it's checked by default for standard Eclipse's Java main class)

[image: Exclude test code]

Comment: I have exactly the opposite problem. Java application->New configuration is not checking "Exclude test code" by default, while STS is. This happened after upgrading to Eclipse 2020-09.

Comment: If I delete all the configurations, go to my Application.java and hit F11 and then choose Java Application from the popup, eclipse creates a run configuration with "Exclude test code" checked. So the issue only occurs when manually creating the configuration. Go figure..